# Serverless Error: No file matches include / exclude patterns

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab-ci, serverless-framework

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but none of them has a proper answer. I am trying to deploy my code using GitLab cicd pipeline. While executing the deployment stage, my pipeline failed and got this error.

My serverless.yml has this code related to exclude

```
package:
  patterns:
    - '!nltk'
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!package-lock.json'
    - '!package.json'
    - '!__pycache__/**'
    - '!.gitlab-ci.yml'
    - '!tests/**'
    - '!README.md'
```

The error I am getting is

> Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
> No file matches include / exclude patterns

I forgot to mention, I have a nltk layer which I am deploying in the same serverless.yml as my lambda function and other resources.

I am not sure what has to be done exactly to get rid of the error. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Can you paste a copy of the error message?

Comment: I know that I’ve had path trouble before with gitlab and artifacts. I was able to work around it by using the predefined CI_BUILDS_DIR variable to make sure the paths were correct. I’m wondering if your experiencing a similar style problem.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure either. The manual deployment worked fine. But cicd pipeline is giving me this serverless error

Answer (score 1):

Your directives do not define any inclusive patterns. Perhaps you want to list the files & directories you need packaged. Each directive builds on the next.

Something like:

```yaml
package:
  patterns:
    - "**/**"
    - '!nltk'
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!package-lock.json'
    - '!package.json'
    - '!__pycache__/**'
    - '!.gitlab-ci.yml'
    - '!tests/**'
    - '!README.md'
```

See https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/#patterns